# Неправильно отображается свой курсор в Google Chrome

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome, cursor

Помогите разобраться в проблеме.
Устанавливаю свой курсор на сайт через `CSS` свойство `cursor`. Но возникает проблема. Если масштабирование в системе (Windows 7-10) установлено больше 100%, например, 150%, то в `Chrome` курсор становится пиксельным (неровным). Проявляется это только в `Chrome` и ему подобных браузерах. В `Firefox` все хорошо.
 Больше всего это заметно на круглых курсорах, например, курсор лупы. Курсор в формате `svg`, но так же пробовал `png` и `cur`. Разницы нет. Ситуацию немного улучшает прописывание в svg свойства `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` но несущественно. Сама картинка отображается как нужно, если она не установлена как курсор. [Ссылка на курсор SVG](https://dropmefiles.com/do1ta)

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: А вариант с стандартными `cursor: zoom-in` и `cursor: zoom-out`не устраивает? [Кроссбраузерность](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/6b0544a4-480e-4b39-8868-c3df319893fd.png)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 К сожалению, нет. Но, видимо, придется использовать стандартные курсоры.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось это известный [баг](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=325565) и адекватных решений на сегодня нет. А явление это называется "видимый aliasing".